# Passing large text-data through intent. How to cache it?

Tags: android, caching, android-intent, android-lru-cache

I'm passing some data to DatabaseService through an Intent. 
However there is a corner case of one user when this data is really huuuge. And I get

`E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`

Bummer.

Normally people assume that I try to pass a bitmap to (though?) a LruCache. Okay, can I use if for like an array list of objects? As I said - in fact this is a response from server, which is a JSON.

Any ideas how to solve this? 
Is there a special class for this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** Store json data in db and then access data from db in your activity

**Option 2.** Store data in a centralized object (singleton etc) & then access that object in Activity.

Let say you have a single class AppData.
Store data in AppData.
Access data using AppData in your activity directly.

**Option 3.** Parse json to corresponding entities/models, make them [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), then Store parcelable data in preference.

[How to make entity parcelable with just copy paste](http://parcelabler.com/)